# How to call a function on an inner class

Tags: kotlin

The following code is posted on Kotlin's website:

```
class A { // implicit label @A
    inner class B { // implicit label @B
        fun Int.foo() { // implicit label @foo
            val a = this@A // A's this
            val b = this@B // B's this

            val c = this // foo()'s receiver, an Int
            val c1 = this@foo // foo()'s receiver, an Int

            val funLit = lambda@ fun String.() {
                val d = this // funLit's receiver
            }


            val funLit2 = { s: String ->
                // foo()'s receiver, since enclosing lambda expression
                // doesn't have any receiver
                val d1 = this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It isn't clear to me how you call a function in an inner class. For example, how do you call Int.foo()

```
var a = A()
a.Int.foo() // This is not allowed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets look at a more simple example:

```
class A { 

    inner class B { 

        fun foo() { 
          // ...
        }
    }
}
```

To call a function within an inner class, you must access it using an instance of the outer class, like so:

```
A().B().foo()
```

What makes your example more difficult is that `Int.foo()` is an extension function, so to access it you must call `foo()` on an `Int` within the same scope as the extension function:

```
class A { // outer class A
    inner class B { // inner class B
        fun Int.foo() { // entension function foo
            print("Foo called on integer $this")
        }

        fun caller(i: Int) { // calls extension function
            i.foo()
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    A().B().caller(10)   // calls extension function in inner class B
}
```

Here we have added a function `caller` which is in the same scope as the extension function. The code outputs the following:

`Foo called on integer 10`

Comment: Can you please provide an actual example of calling "foo on an Int within the same scope as the extension function". Thank you.

Comment: That clarifies it but I now realize that you cannot call an extension function (Int.foo). It has to be through another function that is not an extension (caller)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `foo` is an extension function defined in `B`. You cannot call these [member extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members) from outside by default. However, it's possible to execute the function when you get into the scope of `B`, which can be achieved with scoping functions such as [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html). Please be aware that this extension function can only be called on instances of `Int`.

```
val a = A()
val b = a.B()
with(b) {
    5.foo()
}
```

Comment: Here’s an article I wrote about these functions: https://kotlinexpertise.com/coping-with-kotlins-scope-functions/ but actually with is the best option for these scenarios. To be clear, this is possible due to the use of *lambdas with receiver*

Comment: This does not compile. It generates an error of "Unresolved reference: foo". Can you provide an actual example that works? Thanks.

Comment: The code I posted compiles without issues actually. Can you share your version?

Comment: @AndroidDev this code does not work on its own when used in a .kt file, please wrap it in a `main` for instance

Comment: Well, since there is no "main" in an Android app, I can't do that. I tried placing this in the onCreate method of an activity but that didn't help either. It's not important. Just curious why this sample code would get posted on the official kotlin site which is primarily for Android development yet shows no practical way of using it.

Comment: `main` was just an example, should work in any function, also `onCreate`. Want to show the code?

Comment: @AndroidDev I use Kotlin solely in *non*-Android-projects. The shown constellation makes total sense in cases where you want to enhance some classes in a specific context (the more common/standard the classes are, the more appropriate is this constellation). Imagine the following example: `fun String.toPojo()` within your class `PojoReader`. As long as your context is `PojoReader` that function is avaiable to strings, but you probably do not want to make it generally available (even more so, if the `PojoReader` requires additional setup/configuration to even transform strings to POJOs).